# How to handle unsupported system commands in Python?

Tags: python, operating-system, command, system

I would like to ask if there is any solution to handle unsupported system command in Python. E.g.:

```
import os
os.system("svn")
```

In this code I tried to use svn command and I get an error:

```
"svn" is not recognized as an internal or external comand...
```

It's obvious, because I didn't install svn, that's why I have got this error etc. The question is not about "svn", but in general command which is not supported by opereting system. Is there any possiblity to handle such event in Python and if such situation occurs there will be info that this command is unsupported by your system.

Comment: You might want to use `subprocess` instead of os.system => `subprocess.call("svn")`. You can catch the error from the operating system with the status returned by the call function.

Answer (score 1):

`os.system` returns many different codes upon completion but `subprocess.call` can be caught.

```
try:
    subprocess.call(['svn'])

except OSError:
    print 'an error occurred'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe os.system is deprecated, see this page for subprocess: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module

With the following code:

```
import subprocess
import sys
try:
    retcode = subprocess.call("svn")
    if retcode < 0:
        print >>sys.stderr, "Child was terminated by signal", -retcode
    else:
        print >>sys.stderr, "Child returned", retcode
except OSError as e:
    print >>sys.stderr, "Execution failed:", e
```

You get error:

Execution failed: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Use `subprocess.check_call`, catching a `CalledProcessError` and a `FileNotFoundError`:

```
from subprocess import check_call, CalledProcessError

try:
    check_call(["svn"])
except CalledProcessError as e:
    print("There was an error calling {}".format(e.cmd))
except FileNotFoundError as e:
    print("Invalid command")
```

It will also raise an error if the command returns a non-zero exit status.

The `os.system` command is depreciated as are os.popen etc.. You should always use the subprocess module.